# Executing a bash file from a php page with root-only commands (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, bash, file, ubuntu, apache2

I need to execute a bash file from a php page, with exec() function. The problem is that in this bash file, there's the command "adduser" ... Witch is a sudo command. I had the idea of modifying the sudoers so the user that run the script would have access to it, but who is this user ? I know apache2 is executated with www-data user...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which user PHP is running as by using system to run the command 'whoami' and display the output.

```
system('whoami');
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a rather bad plan, giving the www-user sudo access. But yes, its www-data (by default, depending on linux flavor) that apache runs under.

Comment: Would you have a better idea to create ftp users via PHP ? It's what I'm trying to do...